# Should we import a whole library or a specific individual component when using along Create-React-App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, deployment, create-react-app

I am asking this on performance/optimizing issue. I realize that all libraries (and their default export method) are different but for example on react-bootstrap's [doc intro](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) it states that

> You should import individual components like: react-bootstrap/Button rather than the entire library. Doing so pulls in only the specific components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you end up sending to the client.

Since we are in 2019, does Create-React-App's (CRA) build automatically optimize for us and only import those components who have been used at least once?

If so, does that mean that we can ignore the advice and import the whole library instead of specific components?

Comment: CRA relies on Webpack, which is responsible for tree-shaking. Webpack analyzes all imports for possible side effects (i.e. the named import uses other functions that also need to be imported). Tree-shaking relies on the 3rd party lib to properly write components that do not have side effects. 

I would follow the advice of the library you are using, Bootstrap, which is telling you exactly how to import the Components to reduce the bundle size. Don't ignore their recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the two examples given by the docs:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

This is the recommended way to import. In this case, you are explicitly importing the component from the library.

```
// or less ideally
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

This method imports the entire library and adds the Button component to the scope of that file. This case uses Webpack's tree shaking functionality to reduce the bundle size, which is not entirely reliable. This article provides insight on why that's the case: https://advancedweb.hu/2017/02/07/treeshaking/